# Animated ticker in javascript with clickable objects - direction issues with the svg objects

Tags: javascript, html, animation, hyperlink, ticker

UPDATED 11/04-2023

So I am trying to create an animated ticker using javascript and svg text elements however I have got something wrong with my animation  <s>direction not being straight across the screen horizontally and instead it goes leftward and downward, and it only does it up in the left corner of the screen</s> this is driving me nuts!

To those suggesting I use some framework other than javascript, even libraries don't! as I am trying switch back to a "no frameworks" solution for my site as it seems no matter what you choose, all these frameworks and libraries that make your site looking all nice and lovey dovey  get hacked and then you site is in the proverbial gutter and you need to rebuild. So this time I am KISS'ing it - This is the code I have so far, it is almost there it just stops before exiting fully now.

Updated code

```
    '''


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SVG Ani w/Clickable</title>
  <style>
    body, html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #svg-container {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .svg-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: auto;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .svg {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .svg text {
      fill: #333;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="svg-container"></div>

  <script>
    const links = [
      { text: 'Welcome to a soon fully revamped site - using AI to construct it - click to learn more.', href: './aiwork.html' },
    ];

    const duration = 9000;
    const spacing = 20;

    function createSVGObject(link) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('svg-container');

      const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
      const text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
      const a = document.createElement('a');

      text.setAttribute('y', '20');
      text.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif');
      text.textContent = link.text;
      
      svg.appendChild(text);
      a.appendChild(svg);
      div.appendChild(a);
      
      a.setAttribute('href', link.href);
      a.setAttribute('class', 'svg');
      
      const computedWidth = text.getComputedTextLength();
      div.style.width = (computedWidth + 10) + 'px';
      svg.setAttribute('width', (computedWidth + 10) + 'px');
      svg.setAttribute('height', '30');
      svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${computedWidth + 10} 30`);
      svg.style.overflow = 'visible';

      return div;
    }

    function animateSVGObject(object) {
      object.style.top = '0';
      object.style.left = window.innerWidth + 'px';

      const startTime = performance.now();
      requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
        const progress = (time - startTime) / duration;
        const distance = (window.innerWidth + object.getBoundingClientRect().width + spacing) * progress;
        const currentPosition = window.innerWidth - distance;
        object.style.left = currentPosition + 'px';

        if (currentPosition + object.getBoundingClientRect().width > -object.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            object.style.left = window.innerWidth + 'px';
            animateSVGObject(object);
          }, duration * links.length);
        }
      });
    }

    links.forEach((link, index) => {
      const svgObject = createSVGObject(link);
      document.getElementById('svg-container').appendChild(svgObject);
      setTimeout(() => animateSVGObject(svgObject), duration * index);
    });

  </script>

  <p>SVG</p>

</body>
</html>
    '''
```

<s>Any takes on what I am doing wrong with the directionand why the svg does not animate all the way across my screen horizontally ?</s>

Comment: Seems there have been several issues with the code - I will post as comments as I progress. First issue was the following. The problem with the SVG animation not moving in a straight horizontal line is due to the #svg-container height being set to 30px. The SVG text elements have their y attribute set to 20, which means that they are rendered 20 units lower in the SVG coordinate system, and this causes the downward movement.

To fix this issue, you can update the #svg-container height to match the height of the viewBox in the SVG elements.

Comment: Then there was the issue with fonts enlarging. This due to the browser's behavior when scaling SVGs with a fixed viewBox. To resolve this issue, one can wrap the SVG element in a div container, set the container size, and remove the viewBox attribute on the SVG element. The container will then maintain a fixed size during the animation.

Comment: Additionally issues with how the length of the object is calculated, but I have something that is close to working now

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Sorry I was not aware that I should not add the correct code to the question - I thought it would be too long to put in as a comment

Comment: Don't add answers in comments either please. It's what the "Your Answer" dialogue is for. Do add it as answer though! Self-answers are encouraged, as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: But where is the button to do this? Maybe I am too exhausted to see what is right in front of me...

Comment: Can you as a moderator set is as closed in this state? I don't care about points etc. I just know I am not the only one who has struggled with this over the years and am happy to share something that actually seems to work

Comment: Just post it as answer. There's a text dialogue below. First there's a section with links called "Related questions", directly beneath that is a box titled "your answer", just post it in there. See [answer].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I ended up with for now

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>SVG Aninimated Ticker With Clickable Hyperlinks </title>
      
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Einar Petersen - Science Fiction Writer and Technology Enthusiast</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ticker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="banner.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexthumbnails.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navigation.css">
        <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
        
    <meta name="description" content="... - This page in particular contains a SVG Aninimated Ticker With Clickable Hyperlinks">
    
      <style>
        body, html {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }
        #svg-container {
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .svg-container {
          position: absolute;
          width: auto;
          height: 30px;
        }
        .svg {
          display: inline-block;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .svg text {
          fill: #333;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    
    
     
    
    
    <body>
      <div id="svg-container"></div>
    
      <script>
        const links = [
          { text: 'Welcome to a soon fully revamped site - using AI to construct it - click to learn more.', href: './aiwork.html' },
        ];
    
        const duration = 9000;
        const spacing = 20;
    
        function createSVGObject(link) {
          const div = document.createElement('div');
          div.classList.add('svg-container');
    
          const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
          const text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
          const a = document.createElement('a');
    
          text.setAttribute('y', '20');
          text.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif');
          text.textContent = link.text;
          
          svg.appendChild(text);
          a.appendChild(svg);
          div.appendChild(a);
          
          a.setAttribute('href', link.href);
          a.setAttribute('class', 'svg');
          
          const computedWidth = text.getComputedTextLength();
          div.style.width = (computedWidth + 10) + 'px';
          svg.setAttribute('width', (computedWidth + 10) + 'px');
          svg.setAttribute('height', '30');
          svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${computedWidth + 10} 30`);
          svg.style.overflow = 'visible';
    
          return div;
        }
    
        
    function animateSVGObject(object) {
      object.style.top = '0';
      object.style.transform = `translateX(${window.innerWidth}px)`;
    
      const startTime = performance.now();
      requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
        const progress = (time - startTime) / duration;
        const distance = (window.innerWidth + object.getBoundingClientRect().width + spacing) * progress;
        const currentPosition = window.innerWidth - distance;
        object.style.transform = `translateX(${currentPosition}px)`;
    
        if (currentPosition + object.getBoundingClientRect().width > -spacing * 27) {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            object.style.transform = `translateX(${window.innerWidth}px)`;
            animateSVGObject(object);
          }, duration * links.length);
        }
      });
    }
    
    
    
    
        links.forEach((link, index) => {
          const svgObject = createSVGObject(link);
          document.getElementById('svg-container').appendChild(svgObject);
          setTimeout(() => animateSVGObject(svgObject), duration * index);
        });
    
      </script>
    
      <p>SVG</p>
    
       
        <footer>
    <p>© 2023 .... All rights reserved.</p>
    <p>Some material on this website may be subject to different licenses, which will be clearly indicated where applicable.</p>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="...">... on Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Follow ... @ Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Become a patron</a></li>
    
    </ul>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```